# How to declare Array variable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to execute one query in Stored Procedure, that should loop all the array values.

For example:

```
declare arrayStoreID={1001,2400,2001,5000}

for(int i=0;i<arrayStoreID.length;i++)
{
    select 
        col_name1,col_name2
    into
        @temp_table
    from
        Table_Name
    Where 
        storeID=arrayStoreID[i]
}
```

I want to perform like above. 
Thanks

Comment: SQL Server does not support arrays

Comment: I think instead of a loop, you can use a simple 'IN' here, '... FROM Table_Name WHERE storeID IN (1001,2400,2001,5000)'

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is there any other way?

Comment: @AbdulRasheed No, My actual scenario is not like that.

Comment: Use a cursor and a temp-table or table variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare array inside Sql Server Stored Procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732613/how-to-declare-array-inside-sql-server-stored-procedure)

Comment: can you add more details? with expected output and requirement

Comment: There is no such a thing as an array in SQL Server.

Answer (score 13):

First Store IDs in `temporary table` as below

```
create table #Table_Name(storeID INT, col_name1 varchar(50), col_name2 varchar(50))
insert into #Table_Name values
(1001, 'Test1', 'Test2'),
(5000, 'Rest1', 'Rest2'),
(1122, 'Best1', 'Best2')
```

Then you can join with the table from where you want to fetch the record as below, 
    this method is far better than going through the `loop` if your requirement is not `more complicated` in real

```
select t.col_name1,
    t.col_name2
INTO #new_table
from #Table_Name t
inner join #tmp_ids ti on ti.id = t.storeID
```

It will return that two records which is matched with `IDs` and inserted into the 
    `#new_table` above

```
select * from #new_table

OUTPUT:
col_name1   col_name2
Test1       Test2
Rest1       Rest2

Note: you can use `table variable` as well
```

Answer (score 3):

`Array` object is not present in Sql Server.

You can create a temporary table, as follow

```
CREATE TABLE #mytemp (<list of field>)
```

where you can store your information.

You can perform a JOIN operation to use that with other tables or if you want to create a loop you can define a `CURSOR` to process every row of your temporary table

Comment: No brother. My scenario is different. [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/473174/CreateplusArrayplusinplusSqlplusServer). What about this link?

Comment: @mohamedfaisal: Dear, in your link, an array creation as emulated with temp table (Solutiion 1). If you add in your question your aim, I can help you to write a solution

Answer (score 3):

use `IN` clause.

You don't need loop or temp table to pass `storeID`. Pass the list of `storeID's` in `IN` clause

```
 select 
        col_name1,col_name2
    into
        #temp_table -- cannot use @table here
    from
        Table_Name
    Where 
        storeID in (1001,2400,2001,5000)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. No, there is no ARRAY variable in SQL Server
2. No, there is no FOR Loop in SQL Server
3. It is only CURSOR and While loop

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `cursor` attribute

```
declare @col_name1 type,@col_name2 type
declare crsr cursor for select  col_name1,col_name2 from Table_Name Where storeID in (1001,2400,2001,5000)
open crsr
fetch next from crsr into @col_name1,@col_name2 
while @@fetch_status=0
begin
    insert into @temp_table(col_name1,col_name2) values (@col_name1,@col_name2)
end
close crsr
deallocate crsr
```