# I want to create an array in sql with user ids, and create a loop which will pick user id from array

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create an array in sql with user ids, and create a loop which will pick user id from array. And create a user in sql db.

Please find the code below. It is not working as expected :

```
declare type namesarray IS VARARRAY (50) OF VARCHAR2 (10);
declare name namesarray;
declare total integer;

names = namesarray('resh1','resh2');
total = names.count;

while (i <= total)
begin
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create user names(i) identified by newpass01;
    dbms_output.put_line("created user 'names(i)");
end

dbms_output.put_line("cannot create user 'names(i)");
```

Comment: Is it MySQL or sql-server? You have tagged both!

Comment: I am creating a .sql file and writing this inside it. it is sql server

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41671882/how-to-declare-array-variable-in-sql-server/41672324#41672324

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server , it is done as below. You can use table variable.

```
Declare @namesarray table
     (name  varchar(50));

Declare @Name varchar(50);

Insert @namesarray values ('resh1');
Insert @namesarray values ('resh2');

Declare name_cur CURSOR FOR
Select name from  @namesarray ;

OPEN name_cur
    FETCH NEXT FROM name_cur INTO @Name
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            Print @Name
        FETCH NEXT FROM name_cur INTO @Name
        END
    CLOSE name_cur
DEALLOCATE name_cur
```

Comment: so is it like i cant just create a array variable and pick from it? Am sorry for asking, but am new to sql.

Comment: No in Microsoft Sql Server, array type is not there.

Comment: Your question was specific to SQL SERVER, tagged so also,So i gave SQL SERVER specific solution. With same logical approch same can be achived in my sql or oracle database.