# How can I order manipulated data that I store in a variable in SQL?

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a variable `@columns` that outputs a set of decimals. For example, `[0.00000]`, `[1.00000]`, `[4.00000]`, `[3.00000]`. These later get used as columns in one of my queries. However the decimals don't get put in any particular order. I would like to order them from least to greatest in `SQL`. I don't see a function that does this.

How can I manipulate the data to do that?

````
SELECT
    @COLUMNS += QUOTENAME(ct.rate) + ','
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT ct.rate FROM
DB.table ct
WHERE ct.ID = @ID
) ct

SET @COLUMNS = LEFT(@COLUMNS, LEN(@COLUMNS) - 1);

PRINT @COLUMNS```
````

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. Also update your question with example code and data that illustrates what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @NickW I edited the post with your suggestions.

Comment: The output of the PRINT statement shows the numbers I explained above in the order 0 3 4 2. I would like it to be in order from least to greatest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare an array inside MS SQL Server Stored Procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732613/how-to-declare-an-array-inside-ms-sql-server-stored-procedure)

Comment: Also, what kind of order is 0 3 4 2 ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you order the data before the array, you will get the output ordered from least to greatest. As you can't use order inside subquery, you can select a TOP MAX(INT) to subquery it.

```
SELECT
    @COLUMNS += QUOTENAME(ct1.rate) + ','
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT  TOP 2147483647 ct.rate FROM
DB.table ct
WHERE ct.ID = @ID
ORDER BY ct.rate
) ct1
```

Comment: @Jtara dont be!!! We learn everyday. Is usually we take the more complex way

Comment: @JTara also I thought at first time arrays in SQL