# how can i create array of datas in Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

And this Response is from the Answer suggested below. Here i need to get hubxdataitem array for every categoryName

```
[{"Categoryname":"General","DisplayOrder":1,
"hubxDataItems":[{"Id":3,"PatientId":40,"CategoryId":1,"ItemTitle":"Height","ItemValue":"158","ItemUnit":"cms","IsTestDone":true,"ClinicianHubXSign":0,"isAprrovedStatus":false,"isActive":true,"isDeleted":false,"Createdby":1,"CreatedDate":"2022-06-30T22:59:18.7448072","IsTestApproved":true,"PhySignDate":"2022-08-29T05:40:32.2733333"}]},
{"Categoryname":"Mental","DisplayOrder":27},
   i expected "hubxDataItems" array here too
{"Categoryname":"Hemoglobin","DisplayOrder":28},
   i expected "hubxDataItems" array here too
{"Categoryname":"SP02","DisplayOrder":3}]
   i expected "hubxDataItems" array here too
```

Comment: Your code (`.. [dbo].[GetClinicianHubXSign] ..`) seems to be specific for MS SQL, not for MySQL...

Comment: made the changes

Comment: can we achieve the above code??

Comment: I don't think that sql server knows arrays, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732613/how-to-declare-an-array-inside-ms-sql-server-stored-procedure) can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired results are unclear. But it seems you could use something like a nested `FOR JSON` clause.

```sql
Select  
  hdc.Categoryname,
  hb.hubxDataItems
FROM HubxDataCategory hdc
OUTER APPLY (
 SELECT
  hb.Id,
  hb.PatientId,
  hb.CategoryId,
  hb.ItemTitle,
  hb.ItemValue,
  hb.ItemUnit,
  hb.IsTestDone,
  isNull([dbo].[GetClinicianHubXSign] (hb.patientId,hb.HTAID),0) ClinicianHubXSign,
  isnull([dbo].[GetHubXApproveStatus] (hb.patientId,hb.HTAID,hb.CategoryID),0) isAprrovedStatus,
  hb.categoryname,
  hb.isActive,
  hb.isDeleted,
  hb.Createdby,
  hb.CreatedDate,
  hb.UpdatedBy,
  hb.UpdatedDate,
  hb.DeletedBy,
  hb.DeletedDate,
  htap.IsTestApproved,
  htas.createddate as PhySignDate,
 FROM HubxDataItems hb  
 left join HubxTestApprovedForPatient htap on htap.HTAID = hb.HTAID
 left join HubxTestApprovedSignature htas on htas.HTAID = htap.HTAID
 WHERE hdc.Id = hb.categoryId
   AND hb.isActive = 1
   AND hb.IsDeleted = 0   
 FOR JSON PATH
) hb(hubxDataItems)
FOR JSON PATH;
```

Comment: i want to add hubxdataitem array and pass it the above data that i shown. My question to your question is will the code after Outer apply  will act as an array or not??

Comment: Have you tried it? Yes it will return a JSON array. SQL Server does not have a native Array type

Comment: I have one question after the new array starts it is not printing hubxdataitems array data again

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, and I can't repro it because you haven't given sample data. Please give a [mcve], maybe use https://dbfiddle.uk to construct your data and query

Comment: I have updated the question.Under my expected result i have shared a json response data. In that response data  "hubxDataItems":  array is printing for every categoryId. But the answer you gave it is printing hubxDataItems array only once.Ill share the response i get from the answer you gave for better understanding

Comment: Again: without proper sample data I have no idea what is wrong with that. I put a join clause in the subquery `WHERE hdc.Id = hb.categoryId` but I don't know if that's correct because I can't see your table design. Please use https://dbfiddle.uk to construct a **runnable** query that shows the problem

Comment: I have updated the response i get from the answer you suggested please compare the two response.

Comment: **Please construct a [mcve] like I said** or I cannot help you further. I have no idea what is wrong with the query as I cannot test it on your data.

Comment: ok ill try to create the table. I have updated the question at the bottom of the question i have mention what i expected please look.Thanks for your time.