# How to select the hardcoded array in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL, if I want to select a hardcoded value, I can do `SELECT 1;` for example, which would return a table with one column and one row with value `1`.
How can I select the hardcoded array in SQL?

So, I want the output to contain one column with two rows, say with values `1` and `2`. How can I do that?

I tried `SELECT 1, 2;` but that returns a table with one row but two columns, what I do not want. I also tried `SELECT (1, 2);` and `SELECT IN(1, 2);` but none of them works.

I use the Microsoft Structured Query Language server.

Comment: I guess you want `SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2`, but what's the purpose of that strange idea?

Comment: This depends on the version of sql server you are using. Anything earlier than 2022 I would use a tally table. For 2022 I would use `GENERATE_SERIES`. In any version using a hard coded list of values is rather cumbersome and strange.

Comment: MS SQL server doesn't support array data type, if you meant to get multiple rows from values, then you could use from (values (1), (2), (3) ...) t(ColName) syntax.

Comment: maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732613/how-to-declare-an-array-inside-ms-sql-server-stored-procedure

Comment: Are you looking for the `TABLE VALUE CONSTRUCTOR`? `SELECT a,b FROM (VALUES (1,2)) a (a,b)`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: "What's the purpose of that strange idea?" - I am developing an application which would use one table which is not available yet. So I am creating a mock table, but I do not want to create a real table, but instead want to generate values in memory, since this is only temporary. I use the stored procedure to return hard coded table. Until now, I was able to return one row with multiple columns, but was unable to figure out how to return multiple rows from this hardcoded table. Thank you.

Comment: "version of sql server you are using" Ms-SQL Server 2019 Developer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select *
from (values (1),(2)) v(value)
```

or

```
select 1 value
union all
select 2 value
```

or (for SQL Server 2022+ and Azure SQL)

```
select value
from generate_series(1,2)
```

Comment: Hurray for `generate_series()`. Now just to wait for my vendor to support 2022.